# Firefox doesn't wait for a page load Webdriverio

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to run my test using `Selenium` and just encountered the problem. I have my test written for the `Chrome` browser. Now I have been trying to run the same tests in the `Firefox` browser, but they failed.

I've started to investigate the problem and found out that `Firefox` doesn't wait until page is fully loaded. Chrome works perfectly.

I am running `Selenium` in docker containers.

Here is my script

```
storeSearch(info) {
        let that = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            browserClient.init()
                .url("http://somewhere.com")
                .selectByVisibleText("#store","Tech")
                // Redirect to a new page
                .setValue("input[name='search']", info.searchCriteria)
                .selectByValue(".featured", 'MacBook')
                .click("button[name='info']")
                .element('.popup')
                .then(function (element) {
                    if (element.state === 'success') {

                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

It doesn't try even to select a store type from the select `.selectByVisibleText("#store","Tech")` and just throws an exception.

> "An element could not be located on the page using the given search
>   parameters (\"input[name='search']\").",

I have tried to add `timeouts` but it doesn't work as well and gives me an error.

```
  browserClient.init()
                    .url("http://somewhere.com")
                    .timeouts('pageLoad', 100000)
                    .selectByVisibleText("#store","Tech")
```

The following error is thrown.

> "Unknown wait type: pageLoad\nBuild info: version: '3.4.0', revision:
>   'unknown', time: 'unknown'\nSystem info: host: 'ef7581676ebb', ip:
>   '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.9.27-moby', java.version: '1.8.0_121'\nDriver info: driver.version:
>   unknown

I have been trying to solve this problem for two days, but no luck so far.

Could someone help, maybe you have some ideas what can cause the problem ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
 .url("http://somewhere.com")
                .pause(2000)
                .selectByVisibleText("#store","Tech")
```

If I put some `pause` statements it works, but this is really bad and not what I expect from this framework. Chrome works perfectly. It waits until loading bar is fully loaded and only then performs actions.

**The problem is in geckodriver I guess, I have tested it the same flow in Python, Java and the behavior is exactly the same.**

Comment: [@bxfvgekd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4671628/bxfvgekd) you kinda killed the question with that `Update`. This is NOT a **geckodriver issue**, not to mention the `.pause()` is not a best-practice. Please consider re-reading my answer and updating/accepting answer accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: please consider closing the question in accordance with my answer/above comment. Again, this is not a GheckoDriver issue and it's **best-practice** to **explicitly wait** for a `WebElement`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing the exact behavior you detailed above, all-green/passing test cases in Chrome, but on Firefox, a different story.

First off, **never** use `timeouts`, or `pause` in your test cases unless you are debugging. In which case, chaining a `.debug()` previously to your failing step/command will actually do more good.

I wrapped all my **WDIO** commands in `waitUntill()` and afterwards, I saw green in Firefox as well. See your code bellow:

```
storeSearch(info) {
let that = this;
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    browserClient.init()
        .url("http://somewhere.com")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser
                .isExisting("#store");  
        }, yourTimeout, "Your custom error msg for this step")
        .selectByVisibleText("#store","Tech")
        // Redirect to a new page
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser
                .setValue("input[name='search']", info.searchCriteria); 
        }, yourTimeout, "Your custom error msg for this step")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser
                .selectByValue(".featured", 'MacBook'); 
        }, yourTimeout, "Your custom error msg for this step")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser
                .click("button[name='info']");  
        }, yourTimeout, "Your custom error msg for this step")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser
                .isExisting(".popup");  
        }, yourTimeout, "Your custom error msg for this step")
        .element('.popup')
        .then(function (element) {
            assert.equal(element.state,'success');
        });
});
}
```

It's not pretty, but it did the job for me. Hopefully for you as well.

**Enhancement:** If you plan on actually building & maintaining a strong automation harness using **WDIO**, then you should consider creating [custom commands](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/customcommands.html) that package the waiting & make your test cases more readable. See bellow an example for `.click()`:

`commands.js`:

```
module.exports = (function() {
browser.addCommand('cwClick', function(element) {
    return browser
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser.isExisting(element);
        }, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element(" + element + ") does not exist")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser.isVisible(element);
        }, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element(" + element + ") is not visible")
        .waitUntil(function() {
            return browser.click(element);
        }, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element(" + element + ") could not be clicked")
});
})();
```

All that's left to do, is import your module via `require()` in your test case file: `var commands = require('./<pathToCommandsFile>/commands.js');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use code in javascript which will be waiting for state of website. 
In C# looks like this:

```
public void WaitForPage(IWebDriver driver, int timeout = 30)
    {
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
        wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into quite a few issues like this with Selenium in Python and C#, unfortunately both in the Chrome and Firefox webdrivers. The problem seems to be that the code gets ahead of itself and tries to reference elements before they even exist/are visible on the page. The solution I found in Python at least was to use the Wait functions like this: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

If there isn't an equivalent in node, you might have to code a custom method to check the source every so often for the presence of the element in x intervals over time.